# What is Cbp and Ctant in this diagram?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, bypass-capacitor, transimpedance-amplifier

I'm using an analog devices tool to simulate a transimpedance amplifier. When I finish my circuit design, it generates some Cbp and Ctant bypass capacitors which I have never seen before. I assume they attach to power for the op amps, but I asked my EE friend and he wasn't sure either. Anyone know what these capacitors refer to?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the names, they are bypass caps for power supplies, two for first opamp, two for second opamp, and two larger tantalum caps for both of them, for bulk bypassing for the circuit globally.

Comment: Your paragraph ends in the middle, maybe you

Answer (score 0):

Cbp is probably a regular ceramic cap and the Ctant is a polarized tantalum capacitor.